# AnyDesk won't run on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: opengl, 19.10

AnyDesk was running great for me on Ubuntu 19.04. Then I upgraded to 19.10, now it won't start. I installed from the anydesk repository and have version 5.4.0. I've uninstalled & reinstalled already.

When I run from the cli all I get is: `(anydesk:18303): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: 07:23:14.100: Window system doesn't support OpenGL.`

syslog contains lots of lines like this afterwards:

```
Oct 25 07:27:21 mrh-laptop gnome-shell[1660]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Oct 25 07:27:21 mrh-laptop gnome-shell[1660]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Oct 25 07:27:21 mrh-laptop gnome-shell[1660]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a general problem with OpenGL being inoperative. Here's how I eventually solved it: [How to repair OpenGL on Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185010/how-to-repair-opengl-on-ubuntu-19-10)