# How to repair OpenGL on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, opengl, 19.10

My system has been upgraded 18.04 > 18.10 > 19.04 > 19.10. This problem started with the upgrade to 19.10.

AnyDesk won't run, gives this error:

```
GdkGLExt-WARNING **: 08:49:56.379: Window system doesn't support OpenGL.
```

Android Studio won't run the emulator, gives these errors:

```
8:51 AM Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))
8:51 AM Emulator: queryConfigs: Could not query GLX version!
8:51 AM Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
8:51 AM Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
8:51 AM Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
8:51 AM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize.
8:51 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Google Earth Pro won't run. It doesn't give an error msg but in the long stack trace the problem seems to begin here:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0(glXCreateContext+0x33)[0x7fc3af903883]
```

glxinfo won't run:

```
$ glxinfo
name of display: :0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

So I have concluded that my OpenGL is just horribly broken even tho this system seems to be running great otherwise.

Graphics card: Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)

installed drivers:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep xorg-video
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all                     1:7.7+19ubuntu12                     amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                  19.0.1-1ubuntu1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                     1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev                   1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                   2:2.99.917+git20190815-1             amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                 1:1.0.16-1                           amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390              390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                     0.1.5-2build2                        amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon                  1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa                    1:2.4.0-2                            amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware                  1:13.3.0-2build1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

Can anyone direct me how to fix/troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after additional hours of searching and pulling together bits from all over, here's how I solved it. Clues in a number of places pointed to the nvidia drivers as a likely culprit. So I did this:

```
# dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                   390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.129-0ubuntu2                     all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.129-0ubuntu2                     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                 390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                  390.129-0ubuntu2                     i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                 390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                  390.129-0ubuntu2                     i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                   390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                    390.129-0ubuntu2                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                     390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386                      390.129-0ubuntu2                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                   390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                    390.129-0ubuntu2                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                            390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-390                          390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                   390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.13                               all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                           390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18                                 all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390              390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Ok, I got plenty of nvidia. The "metapackage" is usually a good place to start...

```
# apt purge nvidia-driver-390
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-common-390 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390 libnvidia-encode-390:i386
  libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 libxnvctrl0 nvidia-compute-utils-390 nvidia-dkms-390
  nvidia-kernel-common-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-390 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-driver-390*
```

Sure enough, looks like getting rid of that one will get rid of all the squatters too, so, ran that command. Followed by...

```
# apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dkms libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-common-390 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390 libnvidia-encode-390:i386
  libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 libxnvctrl0 nvidia-compute-utils-390 nvidia-dkms-390
  nvidia-kernel-common-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-390 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 25 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 366 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Now to see how things look:

```
# dpkg -l | grep nvidia
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.129-0ubuntu2                     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-390                            390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.129-0ubuntu2                     amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-prime                               0.8.13                               all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
rc  nvidia-settings                            435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
rc  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18                                 all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
```

Everything pretty much gone.

Rebooted. And Yippie! AnyDesk, Google Earth Pro, and the Android Studio Emulator all now run. And `glxinfo` spews its pages of stuff.

P.S. Note that as I was doing this I saved all the above from my terminal session and stored it in a file as ~/nvidia.txt so that if my system wouldn't boot, I could hopefully get into a console and re-install everything manually. Thankfully I didn't need to.

Comment: Why did you had to remove the nvidia drivers? I need them :D

Comment: I followed the steps and ended up with 640x480 resolution which I can't change :(

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to 20.04 had the same problem, purged nvidia-331 and nvidia-340 and OpenGL was off and running again. System has been through many upgrades I suppose I should do a fresh install one day.