# I can't run Anydesk on Contabo Ubuntu VPS

Tags: xubuntu

I installed Anydesk on my contabo ubuntu vps, but it's not running.

I followed this direction, http://deb.anydesk.com/howto.html

After it's installed, it's listed on the program lists, but when I click it, nothing happens.

I tried to run in the terminal, run

```
# anydesk
```

but it says `No specified protocal`.

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185010/how-to-repair-opengl-on-ubuntu-19-10) is not working for me, any idea for running anydesk?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: I've added more info my question

Comment: What version of Ubuntu. Keep in mind that Anydesk does not support wayland. (which is the default on e.g. Ubuntu 21.10)

Comment: I installed VPS Ubuntu 20.04 version